# How can I count up how many males and females are in a text file?

Tags: java

going off of the assumption that the file contains 2 columns with the first column corresponding to the females and the second to the males. The txt file can contain more than one row. I basically just want the total number of females and the total number of males in a file. The file is set up with a space separating the 2 columns. rows are separated by pressing enter. for example:

```
1 1
3 4
5 6
```

This is what I have so far for reading in the file. I'm not sure if it would be appropriate to output as an array list or not.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> simCity(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

    f = new File(String.valueOf(scanner));
    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            integers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        } else {
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
    return integers;
}
```

Comment: What does the text file look like? How are the columns and rows separated?

Comment: my apologies. Question is now updated.

Comment: Personally I would do a `Scanner::readLine` and then split the Strings based upon the space.  I feel that there is no need for an array List as there are only two fixed types of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //Use a try with resources so that the scanner is closed on completion
 int maleCount = 0;
 int femaleCount = 0;
 try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f)) {

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        //TODO Check line is not empty whitespace... A good way of doing this is to use StringUtils.isBlank() in Apache Commons
        if (line.length() == 0) {
              //What to do?
        }
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        if (parts.length != 2) {
             //What do you want to do with an invalid line? Skip it? End program?
        } else {
            //wrap in a try catch - what if parts[X] isn't a number?
            //Or check the string contains only digits before parsing using StringUtils.isNumeric() which is part of Apache Commons 
            femaleCount += Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            maleCount += Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        }
    }
}
//Use the counts
```

If you have this in a method you could return the counts in an ImmutablePair from Apache Commons (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html)

Comment: Answers without an explanation are very likely to get downvoted.

Comment: Are the comments not adequate enough

Comment: These comments seem fine.  And very valid points about decisions to be made regarding invalid data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added in to my own code a line that deals with invalid data.

Answer (score 4):

First, prefer returning the `List` interface to the `ArrayList` concrete type, second declare (and initialize) your `List` with two integer values (to represent your female and male sims respectively). Use `try-with-Resources` to avoid a memory leak with your `Scanner` (or explicitly close it). Read each line from the file, split it on white space and parse the two int values. Add them to their respective running total(s). Return the `List`. Like,

```
public static List<Integer> simCity(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Start with a List of femaleCounts = 0, maleCounts = 0
    List<Integer> totals = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 0));
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            // Skip empty lines
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            // Tokenize the line
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            // Add the line count of females
            totals.set(0, Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) + totals.get(0));
            // Add the line count of males
            totals.set(1, Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) + totals.get(1));
        }
    }
    // Return the List of femaleCounts, maleCounts
    return totals;
}
```

It would, perhaps, be even better to define a custom counter type. That way you can keep `female` and `male` totals independently of any `List`, and make your code a lot easier to reason about. It could even contain parsing and addition logic! For example,

```
class SimCounter {
    private int female;
    private int male;

    public SimCounter(int female, int male) {
        this.female = female;
        this.male = male;
    }

    public void add(SimCounter sc) {
        this.female += sc.female;
        this.male += sc.male;
    }

    public int getFemale() {
        return female;
    }

    public int getMale() {
        return male;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %d", female, male);
    }

    public static SimCounter parse(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        return new SimCounter(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]), 
                Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
    }
}
```

Then your method can be implemented like

```
public static SimCounter simCity(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    SimCounter counter = new SimCounter(0, 0);
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            counter.add(SimCounter.parse(scanner.nextLine()));
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on why you should return the `List` interface instead of an implementation: You don't want to unnecessarily restrict the users of the methods that you write. All you care about is that it's a list, not really what kind of list it is.

You could even return a `Map` that has a key-value pair for females and males (notice here you would return a `Map` and not a `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` or something else. Any type of `Map` will do). Hope this helped clear that up. A lot of newer Java programmers don't think about this, and I liked that it was mentioned.